# I am unable to capture Rest API's in soapui with proxy

Tags: rest, api, proxy, soapui, web-api-testing

I am using soapui(version 5.3.0) open source for API testing .
I want to fetch all Rest API's with proxy . But proxy is not working .

Can anyone help to solve out this problem with steps.

I tried the following steps.
1. In preference section step 2 (proxy setting )added host and port
2. same proxy setting is made on Firefox browsers
3. and launched HTTP monitor.

Unable to capture any API's with proxy.

But we can capture API's in postman etc with proxy.

Need to confirm the following things

1. If soapui does not support capturing rest API's till now for open source.
2. If yes how can i capture the rest API's.